# JMeter Result Analysis and Trend plotting

Tags: jmeter

Current Situation:
I am using JMeter for doing the Performance regression of my application. The scripts are prepared and are executed every night.

I am also using JMeter plugins to capture the PerfMon stats and JMX stats during the test. The response time stats, perfmon stats and JMX stats are all stored in the file in csv format.

Problem Statement:
Q1: The daily analysis of the results is tedious task. Also, we want to plot the daily trends of Response time and Server metrics and share it with larger group. Do you have any suggestions on available tools (open source/ free preferred) that can help us to plot daily trends for response time and server metrics.

If we have to develop our own tool then...
Q2: While plotting the trend, what will be the best way to convey the regression status with minimum number of graphs? Our suite has more than 200 samplers and is growing every month. Plotting the daily trends for 200+ samples in a graph is very confusing for the end audience. Can you suggest a way where I can get a single number to plot the daily trend.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend going for [Jenkins](http://jenkins.io/). With [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) it can

- execute JMeter tests on demand or automatically basing on many possible triggers
- plot performance trend basing on previous execution results
- conditionally fail the builds in case of e.g. response time exceeds a certain threshold
- and many more. See [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article for more detailed explanation on Jenkins, Performance Plugin and JMeter installation and configuration.

Another possible solution could be using JChav - [JMeter Chart History and Visualization](http://jchav.blogspot.com)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Sorry for late reply. I will try out both the options you have mentioned and will let you know what we have chosen.

Comment: Dmitri, where can I get the image files that Jenkins performance plugin creates when we click on performance trend? I want to export those images to my team on Slack.